# Was Toto's song "Good For You" influenced by the "Minder" theme song?

Tags: soundtrack, influence

The first time I heard Toto's *Good For You* from their album *IV* it reminded me of the [*Minder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minder_%28TV_series%29) theme song, not just lyrically but musically as well. Is there any connection or is it just a coincidence?

*Minder* theme song as sung by Denis Waterman:

> I could be so good for you. I'm gonna help ya!
>   Love you like you want me to. I’ll do anything for you … I’ll be so good for you.

Toto - *Good For You*:

> I could be good for you,
>   you could be good for me too

Answer (score 2):

Very very unlikely -

[Good for You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RcZhdyXsEk) - from the album Toto IV, 1982

[I Could Be So Good for You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRR-x9JZ_Oo) - Minder theme, ITV series 1979.

It's not an uncommon sound, though.
It's what I'd call 'Pub Rock with a hint of Chas & Dave' - well, the Minder theme, not Toto ;)

The music was written by [Gerard Kenny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_Kenny), an American jobbing songwriter in the UK with sufficient background & experience to be able to write to a brief - in similar vein to such as [Mickie Most](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickie_Most) & his school of writers, Nicky Chinn, Mike Chapman, et al.
(There's another guy wrote TV themes in similar style around that time - when I can remember his name I'll add him)

Personally, I feel the 'builder rock' genre simultaneously reached its pinnacle & nadir with Auf Wiedersehen Pet's intro - [That's Livin' Alright](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I3XplJD2l0) & outro in quieter vein [Breakin' Away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_OcFCs8Rnw) [which I always felt owed a lot to Roger Daltrey's [Giving it All Away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWAsHoDIlGk)] -  though it possibly started with [Whatever Happened to The Likely Lads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maLeIOT3aeo) - even allowing for the fact that was kind of doing a post-Beatlesque meets the Wombles thing too.